# Can not read access folders WKWebView when navigating through Drop Down Menu

Tags: swift, webview, drop-down-menu, directory

In my app I have a drop down menu. And I have a package that contains folders and inside folders there are files. When I try to navigate through the drop down menu, it loads the files that are in the same folder but if I try to navigate to a file that it's not in the same folder, it would not load it.

I am using this line of code to load a file url

```
_ = webview?.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: readAccessFolder)
```

Loading HTML code:

```
func loadHTML(forSection section: Int) {

    URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
    URLCache.shared.diskCapacity = 0
    URLCache.shared.memoryCapacity = 0

    if section > sections.count {
        return
    }

    if webview?.isLoading == true {
        webview?.stopLoading()
    }

    if let urlString = sections[section]["url"], let contenttype = sections[section]["contenttype"], let readAccessFolder = readAccessFolder {

        var url = URL(fileURLWithPath: urlString)

        if var components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false), contenttype == "requirements" {

            let sc = URLQueryItem(name: "shoppingcart", value: "true")
            let domain = URLQueryItem(name: "domain", value: "*")
            components.queryItems = [sc, domain]
            if let newUrl = components.url {
                url = newUrl
            }

        }

        _ = webview?.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: readAccessFolder)


    }

}
```

**How to fix this issue?**

Comment: You question is not clear. But what I understand, I guess paths of the file you are loading into uiwebview are incorrect, if you supply correct path it will definitely work.

Comment: @ayon I have the correct path and I double checked this.

Comment: Can you share your codes ?

Comment: @ayon the code is added in the question.

Comment: @ayon The funny part is that if I do this let htmlString = try! NSString(contentsOfFile: url.path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            _ = webview?.loadHTMLString(htmlString as String, baseURL: url), and load it as a "loadHTMLString" it works and you can access paths from other folders but with "loadFileURL" I can not. I think it has issue with allowingReadAccessTo and does not give access to the other folders unless you are in the same folder

Comment: implement webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType and it's corresponding error delegate. So, every time you click on a link, you'll know whats really going on under the hood.

Comment: @ayon, it did not work.